# Redirecionamento de saída para variável com espaços em branco

Tags: script, shell

Estou fazendo um script onde quero capturar um caminho até o nome de um arquivo do usuário e depois usá-lo, acrescido da extensão, para redirecionar a saída de um comando.

exemplo:
`Insert path: ~/Videos/file`

Faço isso usando "**read -e path**", e depois redirecionando a saída assim:
`foo > ${path}.abc`

Mas se esse caminho tiver espaços, por exemplo, `~/Área\ de\ Trabalho`, dá errado.

Como capturar o caminho de forma que funcione mesmo para aqueles que tem espaços em branco?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: a shell expande variáves entre aspas. Tenta: `foo > ~/"$path".abc`

Comment: Usando as aspas funciona o caminho com espaços, mas o uso do ~ para a home se inserido pelo usuário se perde.

Comment: vê se a minha resposta funciona...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta algo como

```
foo >  "${path/\~/$HOME}.abc"
```

Em que

- as apspas protegem os espaços
- `${var/pat/sub}` substitui o padrão "pat" pelo valor "sub" em `$var`

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!